# Generating sequences of numbers with a for loop

Tags: matlab

Let A = [1,1:1,0] and X_1 = [1,0;0,1]

Compute X_k+1 =AX_k, for 1:5 using a for loop and report the results for each k.

```
for k = 1:5,
  x(k+1) = A*x(k);
  fprintf('y(%d) = %16.8f\n',k,x(k));
end
```

This does not work and I honestly don't understand how to fix it

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what's wrong. `A` and `X_k` are both matrices so their product is also going to be a matrix. `x(k+1)` is a scalar index. Use a [cell array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) or a [3D matrix](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/multidimensional-arrays.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, `k` refers to the state of the matrix `X` at the `k`-th iteration, not the `k`-th element.

```
A = [1,1;1,0];
X = [1,0;0,1];
for k = 1:5,
  X = A*X ;
  disp(['X at iteration ',num2str(k)]);
  disp(X);
end
```

You could store the values of `X` for each iteration, but I rarely feel that's necessary for a fixed-point iteration.

Comment: Alright thank you for your clarifying what is was asking as well as giving a solution!

Comment: How would I print out just the 5th term? X(30)

Comment: @RyanPorter Move the `disp` function calls to after the `for`-loop.

Comment: Thank you again for the help